# android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked not toggling in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, checkedtextview

Here is my custom adapter:

```
...
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, parent, false);
    return v;
}
...
```

Now this visually appears to be exactly what I needed. The problem is that I can't get toggle the checked state when I click on the listview item. Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I quickly found a sloppy way of doing this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)v;
    textview.setChecked(!textview.isChecked());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mohit,
Why don't you try this:

```
@Override 
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)v;    
    textview.toggle();
}
```